# Why doesn't my redirecturl work for my json object in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a problem reaching my final action method in my mvc application. I've searched for errors, and it's probably something simple, but I can't find it.

So I have an AJAX-call on a button which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#registerUser").click(function () {
                var $username = $("#registerName").val();
                var $email = $("#registerEmail").val();
                var $password = $("#password").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Home/RegisterUser',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        username: $username,
                        email: $email,
                        password: $password
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location.href = response.Url;
                        },
                    error: function(data)
                    {}
            });
            });
        });
```

I then recieve the data in the following action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterUser(string username, string email, string password)
{
verify user, save to db

            var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("LoggedIn", "Home", new { Id = user.Id });

            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

I then want to hit this action method, but for some reason i never reach it.

```
public ActionResult LoggedIn(int id)
{}
```

Comment: what says the network log in the development tools of your browser?

Comment: im not used to working with that tool, anthing particular you are looking for?

Comment: You are looking for the response headers/body and status code.

Comment: press f12 in your browser, you should get a panel with development tools with a tab called network or something, make your ajax call and see for that request the response to check that the action is returning the proper url. Another option is to access the action directly to check the result

Comment: I swear i didn't change a thing, but now when i tested it, it worked. I then tried once again right away afterwards and then it didn't reach it.

I cant really find what you are asking for. i dont see anything with thoose names

Comment: Which browser are you using? And do you know how to open its debug console?

Comment: Im using chrome, i tried firefox as well. I know how to use the console, but i've never worked with the network tab before.

here is what i think you are looking for: http://pastebin.com/qj9FJbaG

Comment: in that tab you get a log of all request you have done, look for the request you made to Home/RegisterUser and pastebin the content of the response tag for that request

Comment: Ok i found the error. The application was losing connection to my localdb that i created and therefor it couldn't create the user and hence i didn't have an ID which made the json url fail. Im sorry for taking up your time. Ive tried locating the problem for 5 hours now and was about to give up :/